# The Response Time of URL more than 8 min on UI, we are Not getting Response time in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, response

I am Trying to Run jmx file for which Expected Response time is 8 min for single User, But jmeter is NOT responding at all even after 1 hour below are the Log files

Is there any Settings in jmeter where jmeter will not respond after certain amount of response time

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter will wait for response **forever** (or as long as underlying operating system and/or [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) allow)

If you want JMeter to mark sampler as failed after 8 (or what is your maximum threshold) minutes - set the reasonable response timeout. It can be done under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

If you have more than 1 HTTP Request sampler and want to apply the same timeout to all of them - go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/new-blazemeter-guide-311365/23622)

Comment: Actually JMeter is NOT Responding, if we give time out of certain duration (15 min) it is failing due to Socket closed/timeout Error.

Actual thing is when response time on UI is 8 min , so Jmeter should also provide Some response  around 8 min but it is pretending as it is  hanging

Comment: JMeter isn't designed to "respond", it sends [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) requests and waits for the response. If you get response in "UI" (whatever it is) and don't get it in JMeter it means that you simply sent a different request. Make sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and retry. Be informed that JMeter cannot execute client-side JavaScript, it might be the explanation for the behaviour you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, Below is the Exact issue it would if i get some help in handling it
 
it is Taking 8 min to Load a Request (Wait for Server Response Time is 8 Min) 

But in JMeter when i am loading the same Request there is No Response